# Htaccess for redirecting escaped characters

Tags: .htaccess

Somehow php urldecode is not working - hence looking for an alternate way through htaccess for redirecting 
Which is the best way to redirect

Wrong url

```
http://www.example.com/index.php%3Foption%3Dcom_toys%26view%3Dproduct%26Itemid%3D2%26id%3D8%26vid%3D175
```

Htaccess Code - it somehow redirecting to 404 page

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\%3[fF]option\%3[dD]([^\ ]+)\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php http://www.example.com/index.php?option=%2 [R=301,L]
```

by giving final output URL as

```
 http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_toys%2526view%253Dproduct%2526Itemid%253D2%2526id%253D8%2526vid%253D175
```

Desired URL is

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_toys&view=product&Itemid=2&id=8&vid=175
```

Comment: What do you mean by: "urldecode is not working"?

Comment: i mean to ask - i am not finding a right way to implement it on site. Tried many strings - but the problem is occurring in hundreds to thousands of urls like. Guess to get a way through htaccess if possible

Comment: Provided atleast PHP solution, try if it suits your needs. I dunno about .htaccess solution.

Comment: Is the URL encoded twice? In other words are `%3F` in the actual URL, it's not simply an encoded `?`? Normally, any URL encoded (percent encoded triplets) are automatically decoded server-side. mod_rewrite matches against the %-decoded URL, so instead of trying to match `%3F`, you would match against the literal `?`, etc. TBH, your "wrong URL" looks malformed - it's been encoded incorrectly?

Comment: Tip: test any redirects with a 302 (temporary) redirect in case you get it wrong first time. 302 redirects aren't cached; 301 redirects are - which causes additional problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to decode your url:

```
<?php
  function utf8_urldecode($str) {
    $str = preg_replace("/%u([0-9a-f]{3,4})/i","&#x\\1;",urldecode($str));
    return html_entity_decode($str,null,'UTF-8');;
  }
$current_url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$decode = utf8_urldecode($real_url);
echo $decode;
?>
```

Then you should have no problems at all.

Comment: Thanks Eda, but will it slow the page as URL will be called and second - would it right way to implement code through Template as that will cover all the urls

Comment: I dont know what are you using your URL for, so I cannot tell about slowing the page, but there is difference about 0,000001 seconds when I test that on blank page. Also....yes. You can add the function into your template, or functions.php file and it will work everywhere. I could edit it a bit so you could just call the function without parameters, to always decode your current url.

Comment: Ok - I used the code exactly as mentioned in my template file - but there's no effect on the URL. Have cleared cache also - but still the code is not decoding ascii characters in url

Comment: Ok - herein ($real_url) will be replaced with $current_url - but then its echoing the output url on the page - if used in template. Its not correcting the page URL though

Comment: Well you did NOT specify what you want to do with the URL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73489/discussion-between-ruchika-and-eda190).